# How can I enable fingerprint authentication on a Mac? What compatible scanners are available?

Tags: macos, security

Do you know if there's a way to have fingerprint authentication on Mac? If so, is there any scanner compatible available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - you will want to start with the [Smart Card services](http://smartcardservices.macosforge.org) source code or compiled installer that Apple publishes and then pick whatever device you like that integrates to this infrastructure.

Here is Apple's starting point and a few more links that may help you in your search for a biometric authentication solution:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10872
- http://www.cac.mil/common-access-card/managing-your-cac/
- https://www.dmdc.osd.mil/smartcard/owa/ShowPage?p=faqusers#fingerdeers
- http://www.cacsecurity.com/biometrics.asp